# Connecting multiple monitors through USB C adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, usb-c

I am using a USB C adapter with my laptop which has Ubuntu 21.04 installed. I am only able to use one HDMI cable at a time and cannot connect two HDMI cables at once. I am able to connect multiple monitors if I connect one through the HDMI port on the adapter and one through the VGA connector on the adapter but that presents a different issue in regards to the resolution. I was wondering if there is any way to fix this?

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:159 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:50000000- 
5fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please add some more data to your question. Are you using displaylink? If, yes, which version of the driver. What GPU and which driver?

Comment: No, I am not using displaylink because I have tried using displaylink and it did not seem to solved the issue and I have added the graphics information above

Comment: Which USB-C adapter are you using?  I tried to help my niece's husband once with one and the adapter would only allow us to hook up through 1 HDMI and 1 VGA regardless of the OS and monitors that we tried.

Comment: This one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Docking-Station-Triple-Display-Gigablit-Ethernet/dp/B081GSRDS5/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=vakos&qid=1620655884&sr=8-1

Comment: I would happy to use the VGA connector but it appears as an "Uknown display" and therefore it would seem I can't change the resolution. I don't know if you experienced the same issue?

Comment: OK, I am not familiar with that one, but have you tried plugging in an USB-C power adapter to it?  It looks as though that one can deliver the power back to the laptop as well as deliver the power to the rest of the attached devices.

Comment: I tried plugging in the USB C power cable into the adapter which successfully powers the laptop but unfortunately, it didn't seem to make any difference